# Circular Content Carousel with jQuery don't work in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I try to use the Circular Content Carousel in the website I'm making (asp.net mvc), but it doesn't work. The content are showing but carousel is not. I don't really know why it's not working. Help me, please.

This is my _Layout.cshtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <!--Carousel Header-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/carouseltemplate/")css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/carouseltemplate/")css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/carouseltemplate/")css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/carouseltemplate/")js/jquery.circularcontent.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/carouseltemplate/")js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/carouseltemplate/")js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/carouseltemplate/")js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must be having some console errors? Did you check for it? Because you've included other `js` files which contains `jquery code` before the `jquery.js` files.. Try keeping `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")` lines before including any other `js` file

Comment: Thank you. It worked. :)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)